# Magento 2 : How to edit invoice PDF

Tags: magento2, invoice, pdf

My language is Hebrew and when I print pdf of invoice, package slip(maybe other pdf's) the letters are flipped(last is first...),how can I fix this ?

> And if I need to edit a core file, how do I do it properly?

thanks.

Answer (score 5):

You can override this file and do your change which you want in PDF

```
vendor/magento/module-sales/Model/Order/Pdf/AbstractPdf.php
```

Comment: And if I change this file in this specific location it won't be changed after an update or something?

Comment: You have to override this file methods.

Comment: ok thanks, you know what I should change in order to reverse back the letters?

Comment: BUT, if you are on a custom theme, you need to move this file into this folder structure: 

/frontend/Vendor/theme/Magento_Sales/-----and the rest I am not really sure of exactly......what would the path be after Magento_Sales?

Comment: I want to change a position of Items ordered in invoice PDF. Have you any idea about this? **@AshishJagnani**